# Optimize Spark to avoid small file size problem - spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes versus coalesce

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a 40gb JSON file and its schema hosted in HDFS (or ABFS), meaning that this file is divided into 128mb blocks behind the scene.

I want to read this file and persist the result in the Parquet format without doing any transformations.

Let's take the following executor configuration :

- `spark.executor.memory : 8g`
- `spark.executor.cores : 4`
- `spark.executor.instances : 10`
- `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes: 128mb`

This configuration means that Spark will be able to read 10 * 4 = 40 partitions (HDFS blocks) in parallel. And the total number of partitions knowing that the input is 40gb would be ~320 (40gb / 128mb ~ 320) if I am not wrong.

With the above configuration and without using the `coalesce` method : the Spark job reads the file block per block, and since Parquet uses the `snappy` compression, each 128mb Spark partition results in a 10mb Parquet file.

This leads to having many little Parquet files and I know that it can decrease the performance of future Spark jobs that will read this Parquet result.

To counter that problem of having many little files, I can use the `df.coalesce(10)` Spark method which will reduce the number of Spark partitions from 320 to 10 without performing a shuffle of the data. I would have 10 files of ~400mb each.

What I can also do is set `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` to `1024mb`, allowing Spark to read and create 1gb partitions instead of 128mb partitions, and the Parquet results files would be ~100mb (knowing that 128mb -> ~10mb, then 1024mb -> ~100mb).

**My question is the following** : In order to optimize the Spark job, is it better to play with the `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` Spark option in my situation? Or to keep it as default and perform a `coalesce` operation?

My guess is that it would be better to increase the `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` because I assume that the `coalesce` partition's reduction adds a step in the Spark job's DAG inside the `save` stage.

But on the other hand, I don't know it can decrease the performance when telling Spark to use `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes : 1024mb` : I know from the Delta Lake documentation that the "optimal" (Parquet) file size is 1gb, but I don't really know why. Feel free to clarify that last point as well if you know!

I know that what is asked here depends a lot on the use case and no generic rule will work for every use cases, that is why I tried to showcase a simple situation with no transformations implied. Let's say that the goal is just to reduce the size of the data for cost-optimization and take advantage of what the Parquet format offers (`snappy` compression, schema included in the file's metadata, ...).

Comment: Do you read your json with `multiline=false`? If it were any other format I'd say `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` is the way to go. Re. json you may want to check this post that sounds legit: https://medium.com/funding-circle/a-tale-of-spark-json-data-source-764fe9ee29ef

Comment: Thank you for your response and for your review! I use `multiline=false` indeed, my json is multiline type. The article is interesting but discusses another scenario with 38k JSON files (mine is one 50gb JSON file stored on HDFS so divided into 128mb blocks behind the scene) and doesn't seem to really address my question.

Comment: multiline=false means that every line must be a self-contained json doc. If you have a single doc then it is not splittable and can only be parsed by a single executor (partitions=1) regardless of your settings.

Comment: "every line must be a self-contained json doc" -> Yes it is the case of my json file, sorry for the confusion. Regarding your second sentence, since the file is stored on ADLS (like HDFS), the json file is split into many blocks of 128mb behind the scene, and this ensure that the file can be read by many executor in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to optimize the Spark job, is it better to play with the
> spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes Spark option in my situation? Or to
> keep it as default and perform a coalesce operation?

To me this is realy different parameter. `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` while decrease your number of partition. this is a good way to reach your goal, BUT as you mention later

> I tried to showcase a simple situation with no transformations implied

there are probably a good chance that you unintentionaly increase the number of partition later in your job.

`coalesce` minimize the amount of data that are shuffled but at the end of your job so I would prefere using this method over `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`

> My guess is that it would be better to increase the
> spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes because I assume that the coalesce
> partition's reduction adds a step in the Spark job's DAG inside the
> save stage.

`coalesce` add work but on your whole job you will have a better number of partition and data inside your task

> But on the other hand, I don't know it can decrease the performance
> when telling Spark to use spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes : 1024mb :
> I know from the Delta Lake documentation that the "optimal" (Parquet)
> file size is 1gb, but I don't really know why. Feel free to clarify
> that last point as well if you know!

A good pratice is to keep file size close to HDFS block size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there are typos in your message which does not make it very clear. Feel free to edit it.
So based on what you said and from the Spark doc : "coalesce" will perform a narrow shuffle (not a full shuffle). But it means that, as you said, it adds work and so there is an additional step in the DAG compared to when only using  a bigger "maxPartitionBytes" value. So for at least for the situation I described with no transformations involved, I would still consider that "maxPartitionBytes" is more efficient than using "coalesce".

Comment: And regarding your last point "keep file size close to HDFS block size", it is a bit in opposition with the fact that the [optimized file size recommended by Delta Lake is 1GB](https://delta.io/blog/2023-01-25-delta-lake-small-file-compaction-optimize/#:~:text=Delta%20Lake%20target%20file%20size,databricks.). Feel free to elaborate on that if you know more.